# A time modifier used with "before"

Tags: grammar

I have made up two sentences below.

> 1. Jack came back at 3pm before I did.
> 2. Tom came back before I did at 7pm.

In (1), I mean, Jack came back at 3pm. I came back after him.
In (2), I mean, Tom came back first. Then, I came back at 7pm.

Is it OK to have a specific time modifier used with "before" in (1) and (2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your example sentences are good, but you need to insert some commas to separate the clauses:

- *"Jack came back at 3pm, before I did."*
- *"Tom came back before I did, at 7pm."*

Comment: Hi J Taylor. Your correction helped me see the better way to express my thoughts.Thank you very much.